# Retrieve String value from Combobox stored in a DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, string, datagridview, combobox

After enter key in Combobox(cell) edit mode it doesnt take current typed value:

Example here is my code:

```
  private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox box = e.Control as ComboBox;
            box.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            box.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            box.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        }

    }

  private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            Column1.Items.Add(value.ToString());

        }
```

If will use same code in other cell which is not combobox then it works. Why is happening this? I get this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: Which line is the NullReferenceException being thrown on? Why can't you identify the problem that way?

Comment: Error is  in string value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class myWindow : Window
{
    ComboBox cbCombo;                        //DECALRE HERE
    InitializeComponent();
    //Other stuff

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            cmCombo = e.Control as ComboBox;          //INITIALIZE HERE
            cmCombo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            cmCombo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            cmCombo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        }

    }

    private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (cbCombo != null) 
                string value = cbCombo.Value.ToString();
            if (value != null && value != "")
                Column1.Items.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This is as far as I go.  Hopefully this helps you get it.  Otherwise,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx

I don't know how else to help you.

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'cbCombo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Declare it outside of the function

Comment: How Will i do this?

Comment: You're killin me smalls

Comment: Take my teamviewer id 689 972 365

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

### 1:

Why are you trying to convert a `string` to a `string`?  Obviously redundant.

```
value.ToString()
```

This literally never needs to happen.

### 2.

You may be getting a `null` reference because you never actually place a value in to your `value` variable.  A couple of things may fix that.  First, I'd try initializing it differently:

```
string value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value as String;
```

Regardless, you can avoid this `null` error simply by checking `value` before trying to place it.  Overall, try this:

```
string value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value as String;
if (value != null && value != "")
    Column1.Items.Add(value);
```

Comment: I get Error CS1061 'DataGridViewCell' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridViewCell' could be found. Also i thing that when i am in edit mode it doesnt take as a value my typed word or characters.I think it works only for selected values.Thats is my problem i think

Comment: try casting it as a `string`.  If that doesn't work, use the `Convert` function.

Comment: No result just an empty field inside my combobox(cell).    string SelectedText = Convert.ToString((dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).FormattedValue.ToString());
                int SelectedVal = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value);
                Column1.Items.Add(SelectedText);

Comment: Are you using a `ComboBox` or a `DataGridVieCell`?  They're different....

Comment: I'm using a datagridview cell as combobox

Comment: So you're trying to get the value from the ComboBox (that you place in a cell), correct??

Comment: Yes.(if you mean datagridview1 preferences - edit Columns - Column1 Type - DatagridViewComboboxColumn. I think my code work only where something is selected in combobox and not when i am in edit mode.

Comment: Then you have your answer...  You don't want the value from the cell.  The cell just holds the combo box.  You want the value from the combo box.

Comment: `string value = box.Value.ToString();`

Comment: True! But isnt the same? There is no cell cause i made as combobox. So there is only Combobox in datagridview. So How will i do this?

Comment: Also i get
Error CS1061 'DataGridViewComboBoxColumn' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridViewComboBoxColumn' could be found

Comment: No.  Not the same.  If the cell is a combo box, you need to get the values from a `ComboBox` type.  The `ComboBox` is in the `Cell`, or rather it acts as a place holder for the `Cell`.  Either way, you cannot pull the information from the `Cell` because the information is stored in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: `string value = box.Value.ToString(); `

Comment: You get it DIRECTLY from the `ComboBox`.  Nothing else.

Comment: Do you want giving you a teamviewer?I cant understand. Sorry